# Javascript button not working for custom profiles

Tags: apex, javascript

I have a javascript button, which is used to get the field value, that field is not added to page layout.
This button is working fine for system admin but for, custom profile its not working
Javascript Code:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/apex.js")} 

if('{!Order.Field__c}' != null){ 
window.parent.location.href=('/{!Order.Field__c}'); 
} 
else{ 
alert("Okay"); 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: have you checked FLS?

Comment: Yes, and this field is editable to progiles

Comment: does this custom profile have atleast read access to the order object, is there an error when you click the button?

Comment: it seems only permission issue either on object or field.

Comment: Yes custom profiles have read access, i am sure this is not access issue as this is working fine when field is added to page layout

Comment: Try querying the order field with the current records ID and see if it works that way instead of directly referencing it in JavaScript.

Comment: If the field is not on the layout consider making the button call a small apex method "sforce.apex.execute" that returns true or false based on querying order field or add the field to layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly access field in this way because if field is not in layout salesforce does not store its value.

So now you have three options.

1. Add field on page layout and then refer here.
2. Query the field using `sforce` here and then check the value.
3. Or call an external webservice(Apex class) and then do the processing there.

I suggest go with option 1 or 2.

Comment: Resolve this problem by writing webservice class then calling it from javascript button.